# 8 digit telephone number with 3 or 4 same consecutive digits, how many possible number?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> In penisular Malaysia telephone numbers ave 10 digits (KL, Selangor, Putrajaya, Genting) or 9 digits (other states). The first two digits are the area code (03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 09). The remaining digits are the local number and cannot begin with 0.

> Due to marketing strategy, telephone numbers with 3 or 4 same consecutive digits have higher demand and they want to sell these numbers. How many possible numbers that they can sell?

I did some searching for this assignment and i found that first i can sketch my question like this
[image]
then it has 5 possible ways,so i calculate it as 9*10^3 = 9000 because the question said that cannot begin with 0.
Then i found that it have over counting that counted twice in other digit
so i do some calculation that i don't know correct or not
= 45000(it has 5 possible way)-3078((1*1*1*1*9*9*10)+(9*1*1*1*1*9*9)+(1*1*1*1*9*9*10)+(9*1*1*1*1*9*9))-468-4-9
= 41441
Is my answer sound right??

Comment: What have you tried? (I come from Singapore, where all phone numbers are 8 digits :( )

Comment: The question is clear but can you kindly show your own effort if possible?